# PHP login with admin and regular user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I literally tried everything on Google but I can't seem to get a solid login with normal users going to one place and admins to another. 
I tried some codes but after they didn't work I kept changing stuff which I probably screwed a bit now.

My database has a table called 'members' including:

```
id - INT - 4
username - VARCHAR - 65
password - VARCHAR - 65
role - VARCHAR - 11
```

The id of the admin is 1 and other users are > 1 that's how I tried to distinguish admin from other users.

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="0000"; // Mysql password
$db_name="London Mobile"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
$link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name") or die ("can't connect");


// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

// $Query is where you run the query, and $rows is where you collect the number of records.
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM MEMBERS WHERE username = username AND password = password");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);


if ($rows == 1) {
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = 'username';
    $_SESSION['role']   = 'admin';
    header("location: admin.php");
}

elseif ($rows > 1){
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = 'username';
    $_SESSION['role']   = 'user';
    header("location: index.php");
}



?>
```

And this is the code for the form I use

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title></title>


</head>

<body>

<header>

</header>


        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
        <table width="260" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <tr>
                <form name="form1" method="post" action="loginna.php">
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3"><strong>Reparatie tracker</strong></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="78">E-mail</td>
                                <td width="6">:</td>
                                <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Code</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </form>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

</body>

</html>
```

An admin should go to --> admin.php and a user should head to --> index.php

Comment: You don't seem to set `$_SESSION['role']`. You shouldn't set the users password in session. You shouldn't store plain text passwords. And you shouldn't add (user supplied) variables directly to the query - use prepared/parameterized queries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and sorry i'm bad with PHP i don't know much about sessions and stuff, any idea how to improve the  given code?

Comment: You shouldn't be sorry you're "bad with PHP", I doubt anyone was born with any PHP skills. If you make the changes above you will be refactoring (changing) quite a bit of the PHP you have. This includes fetching the user that matches the given username, and using the PHP function `password_verify` to verify the given password matches the stored password hash (which you should store when the user registers, use password_hash function). When you have the user you can then simply check which role the user has as you get that from the DB table, and redirect accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed a few things about your code:

1. You are using the database username and password in your query rather than the username and password from your html form.
2. You are manually compensating for SQL injection
3. You are redirecting the user based on the `id` primary key, even though you have a column specific to role.  Using the `id` is probably not the best idea as you possibly can't guarantee that there will be an `id` of 1.

For point 1, use `$_POST['myusername']` and `$_POST['mypassword']` to access the username and password submitted in the login form.  You may want to add some sort of validation to ensure the user has actually provided text in these fields.

For point 2, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  PHPs PDO library handles escaping for you and handles it properly.  Read up about it.  Nettuts has some good tutorials, [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) and [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338).

For point 3, after getting the user from the database, check the `role` column, and redirect the user based on that.

Another thing to be aware of is password security.  Your users probably wouldn't be happy with you if they knew you were storing their actual passwords in your database.  What if your database was hacked and all the passwords and user details released onto the internet?  PHP has a new function [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to make password hashing easy.  Look it up, understand it, implement it.

I've provided an example that you can look through as to how I might implement user login using the setup you have provided.

```
$host = "localhost"; // Host name
$username = "root"; // Mysql username
$password = "0000"; // Mysql password
$db_name = "London Mobile"; // Database name

// TODO: validate user input and return if form submitted with invalid data

try {
  # create a connection handler to mysql
  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db_name}", $username, $password);

  // prepare our query
  $query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id FROM members WHERE username=:username AND password=:password');

  // execute the query using the information submitted in the login form
  $query->execute(array(
      'username' => $_POST['myusername'],
      'password' => password_hash($_POST['mypassword'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT) // when creating your users, you need to ensure the password is hashed correctly too
    ));

  // fetch the results from the query
  $results = $query->fetchAll();

  // check if we have any results
  if (count($results) == 1) {
    // set the session vars based on the returned row
    $user = $results[0];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
    $_SESSION['role'] = $user['role'];

    // redirect the user based on their role
    switch($user['role']) {
      case 'admin':
        header("location: admin.php");
        break;
      case 'user':
        header("location: index.php");
        break;
      default:
        // role not yet supported
        // you could do a special check here for $user['id'] == 1, and redirect to the member section, if you want
    }
  }
  else if (count($results) > 1) {
    // this case shouldn't be possible
    // there should be a constraint when adding users to prevent this possibility
  }
  else {
    // no user found - display some sort of notification
  }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // notify the user if something went wrong with the sql connection handler
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, fetch the User ID when the user logs in. Then use the header('location:filename.php'); if the id is 1 then direct it to Admin.php if else then the other location.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any idea how to do that with the code i gave?

Comment: Ok so here: $query = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM MEMBERS WHERE username = username AND password = password", $connection);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query); $Query is where you run the query, and $rows is where you collect the number of records. You need to change it to if($rows == 1)  $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
    header("location: timeline.php");
}

elseif ($rows > 1) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $_SESSION['admin']=$row['username'];
    $_SESSION['admin']=$row['password'];
    header("location: timeline.php");
}

Comment: Thanks but still not working. if i put a else {} statement at the end it executes that else statement. So it skips the if and elseif.

Comment: Ok try this, run a query to get the Username and Password and if it equals to the values in the DB, then run a query which select's the ID which belongs to the Username. If they username is 1 then use the header location to go to the admin page, otherwise go to the index page.